# neo4j query: using collect to get nested results

Tags: neo4j

My data set is quite complex, but to simplify what I want, I can say that I have a set of discussions that are labeled with date and time and each discussion has a topic assigned. I am trying to find patterns: if topic 1 appears, what is it usually followed by? I am observing daily trends. I currently have the following query:

```
MATCH (start:Label1)
WHERE start.topic = Topic1
WITH start
MATCH (start)-[r:FOLLOWED_BY]->(end:Label2)
WITH count(end) as ecount, r as rel, collect(end.topic) as topic
RETURN DISTINCT(r.day) AS day, topic, sum(ecount) ORDER BY day DESC;
```

Which returns:

```
250    Topic1  2
250    Topic2  1
250    Topic3  3
```

While I want the following:

```
250 Topic1[2] Topic2[1] Topic3[3]
```

How do I achieve this? I tried to use collect and I get an error along the lines: don't know how to compare that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say without seeing the collect that you tried, but what about this?

```
MATCH (start:Label1 {topic: Topic1})-[r:FOLLOWED_BY]->(end:Label2)
WITH count(end) as ecount, r as tel, collect(end.topic) as topics
UNWIND topics AS topic
RETURN DISTINCT(r.day) AS day, collect(topic + "[" + sum(ecount) + "]")
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

Comment: I just noticed the `collect` in the `WITH` clause, but your example doesn't show any rows in which `topic` has multiple values, but I don't imagine that this will work if `topic` is a collection.  You might need a `FOREACH` surrounding the `collect` in the `RETURN`

Comment: Yes, each row has only one value of the topic. The first answer doesn't work. I get "Type mismatch: expected String, Collection<String> or Collection<Collection<String>> but was Integer"

Comment: foreach loop is also giving me an error, or maybe I am not using it correctly? I just used FOREACH around collect.

Comment: I just editing my answer with an `UNWIND` that might work better.  I'm sort of poking in the dark, though, because I'm not exactly sure what end result that you want.

Comment: I wrote how my output looks like. There is only one Topic per line, followed by the number of times it appears. The problem is that multiple topics appear during the day, so for each topic I have a new line with the same day number. What I want to do is to have one day number and then list all topics that appear. The UNWIND answer returned 'Can't use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions.' Thanks for the help!